# How to find a basis of the subspace of$ M_2×_2$ spanned by the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} -b & b \\ -d & d \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

The matrices  are of the form  $A = \begin{bmatrix} -b & b \\ -d & d  \end{bmatrix}$

Where b and d are real numbers.
By my intuition, the basis of this matrix is $$\{\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1  \end{bmatrix}\} $$

But I do not know how to prove it, or if it is enough, since I think it is trivial.

Besides that, another question is what is the dimension of the vector subspace of A is.
I would again guess that because we have only two matrices for basis, the dimension is $1\times2$ or ?

(Note: we have not taken eigenvectors yet)

I was more comfortable doing the same thing with vectors, and I have more trouble with matrices.

Comment: What do you mean by basis of A? Matrices doesnt have a basis? What you wrote is a basis of a matrix subspace where A is in. The dimension of a vector space is always a natural number, so because these 2 matrices a linearly indepedent, the dimension would be 2.

Comment: @BenjaminSt. So let's say the dimension of every 3x2 matrix is 5, because we can have entries a,b,c,d,e that are all in real numbers. If for example d = e, then the dimension is 4. Do I understand this correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your question is:

> Find a basis for the subspace $$H=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}-b & b \\ -d & d \end{pmatrix}; b,d\in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$

In that case, you can find a basis for $H$ as:

$$\begin{pmatrix}-b & b \\ -d & d \end{pmatrix}=b\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}+d\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Therefore, a basis for $H$ is given by $$\beta_{H}=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
and since that $$\dim(H)=\#\beta_{H}=\operatorname{cardinality}(\beta_{H}).$$
So, you have that $$\dim(H)=2.$$

**Remark:**

1. Matrices have no bases, that question makes no sense. Due to the context of your questions, I assume that the correct question is the one I asked at the beginning.
2. [You can prove it] On the other hand, the method you use to calculate a base of the vector subspace is sufficient to guarantee:
   2.1 Linear independence.
   2.2 $\operatorname{span}(\beta_{H})=H$.

Comment: I will keep that in mind when asking new questions. 

So in remark the second point would be: $$\\ \alpha\text{(matrix 1 from base)} +\beta\text{(matrix 2 from base)} = 0$$ iff $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal to zero
2.2) And $span(\beta_H)$ is just the number of basis vectors, thus 2.
Am I correct ?